# Change the Xpert Gallery Joomla module to show images in their own pages with href links to them

Tags: images, links, joomla, module

I have Xpert Gallery module in Joomla. When you click on it, i want to redirect it to another link, not the actual photo.
What I want is when you click on it, to go to another page. Simply put, I want to change the `<a href=...>`, but I don't know where the code is.

[image]